# Content height is not automatically adjusted when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a modal that has a footer and an header. The content has two columns: `LeftSection` and `RightSection`. I want to have the second column fill the height of the content depending on what the first columns height is (which can differ based on content). From the snippet, this means to have the black div go down as much as the red one does.

```css
.Container {
  margin: auto auto;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #8080801a;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #61dafb;
}

.FlexContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.LeftSection {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.RightSection {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.Footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Header"></div>

  <div class="FlexContainer">

    <div class="LeftSection" ></div>
    <div class='RightSection' ></div>

  </div>
  <div class='Footer' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```css
.Container {
  margin: auto auto;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #8080801a;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #61dafb;
}

.FlexContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.LeftSection {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.RightSection {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.Footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Header"></div>

  <div class="FlexContainer">

    <div class="LeftSection" ></div>
    <div class='RightSection' ></div>

  </div>
  <div class='Footer' />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. I knew it should not have been difficult. Never used those properties tough, Going to read about them now. Thank you good sir.

Comment: You are welcome. Did you know? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers